# Remove array from inside a 2d array where value is equal to

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
  0 => 
    array
      'all_sessions_available' => boolean true
      'all_sessions_unavailable' => boolean false
  ....
  22 => 
    array
      'all_sessions_available' => boolean false
      'all_sessions_unavailable' => boolean true
```

I am trying to remove the full array element if `all_sessions_unavailable` = true

I have the following code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($processData); $i++) {
    if ($processData[$i]['all_sessions_unavailable'] === true) {
        unset($processData[$i]);
    }
}
```

However it removes all but the last  array (`22` in this case which happens to be the last array in the overall array if that makes any difference)

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: not 100% sure on this but try iterating from the other side... I think it is changing the indexes as it unsets so instead do "for($i=count($processData);$i>=0;$i--)"

Comment: That worked a treat, make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is changing the indexes as it unsets so instead do

```
 for($i=count($processData);$i>=0;$i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for PHP 5.3+:

```
$processData = array_filter($processData,
                            function ($i) { return !$i['all_sessions_unavailable']; });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($processData as $index=>$session){
    if($session['all_sessions_unavailable']){
        unset($processData[$index]);
    }
}
```

Why don't you just use `foreach()`, it's probably one of the best features in PHP...

Also, unless `all_sessions_unavailable` could contain values other than boolean, you don't have to match it against an exact `true`.